# Why doesn't this angular expression work in my template's directive

Tags: angularjs, templates

I have a directive that uses this template:

```
template: '<div id={{day}} ng-class="daystatus" ng-click="toggle()">{{day | date: "d"}}</div>'
```

the variable date contains a day which when executed renders as follows:

```
<div id="&quot;2015-09-21T22:00:00.000Z&quot;" ng-class="daystatus" ng-click="toggle()" class="ng-binding selectable" role="button" tabindex="0">22</div>
```

Question one: "Why is is placing the double quotes in the string in the first expression?

Question two: As you can see, in this case everything works as expected, but if I try to apply in the first expression to get the same formating as in the second one as such as:

```
template: '<div id={{day | date: "d"}} ng-class="daystatus" ng-click="toggle()">{{day | date: "d"}}</div>'
```

it simply does not render as expected producing the following HTML code:

```
<div id="{{day" |="" date:"d"}}="" ng-class="daystatus" ng-click="toggle()" class="ng-binding selectable" role="button" tabindex="0">22</div>
```

Any clue on why it is behaving like this?

Comment: your `day` variable value should be `2015-09-21T22:00:00.000Z` instead of `&quot;2015-09-21T22:00:00.000Z&quot;` then your template would be `template: '<div id="{{day}}" ng-class="daystatus" ng-click="toggle()">{{day | date: "d"}}</div>'`

Comment: My day variable already was as you menioned, I don't understand yet where the &quot; come from. Anyhow, by escaping the quotes in the attribute everything worked as expected as mentiones by @wZVanG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape the quotes in the attribute:

```js
{
    template: '<div id={{day | date: "d"}} ng-class="daystatus" ng-click="toggle()">{{day | date: "d"}}</div>'
}
```

To:

```js
{
    template: '<div id="{{day | date: \'d\'}}" ng-class="daystatus" ng-click="toggle()">{{day | date: "d"}}</div>'
}
```